# How can I spread these views out evenly?

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to spread out the following TextViews so that they take up the entire screen vertically. I want to leave the buttons as they are on the bottom at that size.

[image]

Here is my XML file....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1.0" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:weightSum="9"
   android:gravity="center"
    >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="SN : "
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/serialNumberView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:layout_weight="2" 
             android:text=""/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Ver : "
             android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/versionView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:layout_weight="2"
              android:text="" 
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Type:"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:layout_weight="1" 

             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/typeView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:layout_weight="2" 
               android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="V1 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vOneView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="V2 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vTwoView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="V3 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vThreeView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="I1 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/iOneView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="I2 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/iTwoView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="I3 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/iThreeView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="VD1 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vDOneView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="VD2 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vDTwoView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="VD3 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vDThreeView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="Temp : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temperatureId" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/celciusFarenheitButton"
            android:text="C/F"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_weight=".33333333333333" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/readButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Read"
        android:layout_weight=".33333333333333333" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/analogsButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Analogs"
        android:layout_weight=".333333333333333" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have changed your `ScrollView` to a `RelativeLayout`, and in each row the Attribute
`android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1`"

The Xml Look Like This:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1.0" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:gravity="center"
    >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="SN : "
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/serialNumberView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:layout_weight="2" 
             android:text=""/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Ver : "
             android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/versionView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:layout_weight="2"
              android:text="" 
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Type:"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:layout_weight="1" 

             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/typeView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:layout_weight="2" 
               android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:text="V1 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vOneView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:text="V2 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vTwoView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:text="V3 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vThreeView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:text="I1 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/iOneView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:text="I2 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/iTwoView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:text="I3 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/iThreeView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:text="VD1 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vDOneView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:text="VD2 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vDTwoView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:text="VD3 : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vDThreeView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:text="Temp : "
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temperatureId" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/celciusFarenheitButton"
            android:text="C/F"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/readButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Read"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/analogsButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Analogs"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I have a similar problem in multiple other layout files, if I were to add the attributes to the TableRows within the ScrollView, would it still come out looking the same? Not necessarily fill the vertical view, since there are already more elements than needed for that, but to space them out nicely like above?

Comment: ScrollView is Supposed to contain an Infinite content, your views will not fit the vertical content, but if you want to maintain a nice look between your rows you can simply use padding for that